# Problem with geting the file with MultipartFile.fromPath() method

Tags: flutter, dart, multipart, android-file

I'm using wechat_assets_picker (i have tried other libraries before):

these libraries return path to the file on example  'Download/LARGE_elevation.jpg' - this is very poor form of path.

When im trying to use this path to upload a file : await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(...)
im getting the error: FileSystemException (FileSystemException: Cannot retrieve length of file, path = 'Download/LARGE_elevation.jpg' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2))

this is probably because the path is not absolute... when i added the '/storage/emulated/0/' it works... but this is not a perfect solution, this can be the other place generally... and on IOS for sure this will be the other path.

How to fix it, or how to get real path to the file having this informations?

Comment: why not working with streams? i bet you can get a stream from your "picker" package, see [MultipartFile](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartFile/MultipartFile.html) base ctor and check `stream` parameter

Comment: generally it works with http.MultipartFile.fromBytes using bytes provided by Asset from image picker, but  1) i want to give users possibility to retry on failure. so i need to store a path to the file
2) i need to show progress of upload and as i tested and see on some issues on github/stackoverflow   progress calculated using method  fromBytes() is not a perfect - its useless,     but if using fromPath() progress is calculated very well

Comment: getting a real filepath is in practice impossible since those packages use `ContentProvider` on Android platform and `ContentProvider` does not provide such a thing like real filepath

Comment: so, can You suggest something in this situation? only idea i have to write this file to temporary app dir until user close notification...

Comment: tried `file_picker` already? it has [readStream](https://pub.dev/documentation/file_picker/latest/file_picker/PlatformFile/readStream.html) property

Comment: somehow i found many libraries but this not :| , looks good thank You very much

Answer (score 0):

May you try again with the picker, and file issues if the path is still not valid for picking? The picker and its underlying plugin photo_manager have been upgraded rapidly, which might be fixed your problem already.